# How to fix CXX1429] error when building with ndkBuild

Tags: java, android

How to fix [CXX1429] error when building with ndkBuild using D:\androd test\Android-Mod-Menu-3.2\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk: Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: D:\androd test\Android-Mod-Menu-3.2\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk
...
D:/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/../build/core/add-application.mk:88: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

source : https://github.com/LGLTeam/Android-Mod-Menu/releases/tag/3.2
[Imahes error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgYT4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it changing the folders name to eliminate the space on it. As in your case: "D:\androd test" to "D:\androd_test"